# How to workaround value-discard or unused warnnings

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, compiler-options

While it is recommended to turn on compiler flags like `-Wvalue-discard` or `-Wunused:implicits` either explicitly or implicitly throught the use of [**sbt-tpolecat**](https://github.com/DavidGregory084/sbt-tpolecat).

Sometimes you need to workarround those, but in a way that makes it explicit; since we generally consider such things bugs and that was the reason for using the compiler flags in the first place.

One, somewhat common, workarroud for those cases is the following `void` function *(courtesy of Rob Norris)*.

```scala
@inline final def void(args: Any*): Unit = (args, ())._2
```

However, such function has two problems.

1. It has a couple of unnecesary extra allocations; namely the **Seq** for the *varargs* and the **Tuple**.
2. It is not part of the stdlib and adding it on all projects is somewhat tedious.

Is there any other good workarroud that works out of the box?

Comment: Why not suppress the warning with `@nowarn` (2.13) or [silencer](https://github.com/ghik/silencer) (2.12) ?

Comment: An alternative to `void` - [`discard` extension method](https://github.com/AVSystem/scala-commons/blob/master/commons-core/src/main/scala/com/avsystem/commons/SharedExtensions.scala#L81)

Comment: @ghik I made the answer a community wiki, so feel free to add those there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 2.13

Since **Scala** `2.13` there are two ways to disable both warnings.

1. Assign the values to an non-existent variable:

```scala
def testFix1()(implicit i: Int): Unit = {
  val _ = i
  val _ = data
}
```

2. Type-ascript the expression to **Unit**:

```scala
def testFix2()(implicit i: Int): Unit = {
  i : Unit
  data : Unit
}
```

We do not have a formal reference or proof, but it is believed that the second option should be *transparent*; in the sense that it should not have any impact in runtime, like extra allocations or unwanted code generation.

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/KGh2L5M8SuK9ZjnMMEIb9g/4)*.

---

## 3.0

As far as we know, the same tricks should work on **Scala 3** *(aka **Dotty**)*.

## 2.12

???

Comment: for 2.12 you can `println` if you are in a jiffy. Had to get a project working and there were some unused errors in tests that I do not intend to run anyways.